# How to correctly formulate this statement

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

Excuse me, if this is too trivial for this board, **but at the end of the proof I want to show that $$ \frac{-b}{2a} $$ is positive. Now it is given that  $b < 0 $ 
and $a> 0$, so of course, the negatives cancel out and if you divide positive real numbers, you can only get a positive result.**

How could you phrase this brickwall of text more elegantly? Or would you not even mention that and just say Q.E.D at that point?

Comment: I would say , "Q.E.D." suffices here. By the way, you can ask questions on every level in this forum, but show some effort , explain what you did and show some context. If you do want to have some text, you can argue : $-b$ is positive.

Comment: I think when you say "if you divde even real numbers", you mean "if you divide positive real numbers"

Comment: That's correct, I'll fix that. Should I have included the whole proof, Peter?

Comment: No, this is just the general way to present questions. The main reason is to prevent that people simply post their homework and beg for a solution, which is however often successful here, unfortunately, because of the reputation that can be earned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

$[\ldots]$ We get $x = \frac{-b}{2a}$. Since $b$ is negative and $a$ is positive, $x$ is also positive. $~~~~\square$